# Uniqueness of objects in shared pointers

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Let's consider code below:

```
class A { 
    string a;
    public A(string a) : a(a) { }
};

class B : public A {
    public B(string a) : A(a) { }
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> x1 = std::make_shared<B>("x");
    std::shared_ptr<A> x2 = std::make_shared<B>("x");

    A* atom1 = x1.get();
    A* atom2 = x2.get();

    A* atom1X = std::make_shared<B>("x").get();
    A* atom2X = std::make_shared<B>("x").get();

    bool condition1 = (atom1 == atom2);
    bool condition2 = (atom1X == atom2X);

}
```

The result is surprising me because condition1 is false but condition2 is true.
Why? Can you explain what is going on here?

I was researching on the internet. I want to understand how it works

Comment: Assuming we fix the code so it actually compiles, ask yourself what happened to the short-lived shared `B` instance from `A* atom1X = std::make_shared<B>("x").get();` *before* arriving at the next line in your code?

Comment: I assume you know *why* `atom1` and `atom2` are different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
A* atom1X = std::make_shared<B>("x").get(); // (1)
A* atom2X = std::make_shared<B>("x").get(); // (2)
```

In these definitions, `std::make_share<B>("x")` creates a temporary `std::shared_ptr` that ceases to exist at the end of the full expression (essentially at the next `;`).  That means that the object each of these pointers points to gets destroyed immediately after being created.

By the time `atom2X` is declared the object pointed to by `atom1X` has been destroyed and its storage deallocated.  It just so happens that the storage previously occupied by the object allocated in line (1) is exactly the right size to hold a `B` object, so it gets re-used in line (2).

---

Essentially, if you remove all of the smart pointers, you can think of your code as being equivalent to this:

```
A* x1 = new B("x");
A* x2 = new B("x");

A* atom1 = x1;
A* atom2 = x2;

A* atom1X = new B("x");
delete atom1X;
A* atom2X = new B("x");
delete atom2X;
```